# Sending Messages From Non-Actors in Akka

Tags: java, akka

If I were to call

```
actorRef.tell("MSG", null);
```

From a non-actor

Is it still thread safe?  And async as in completes immediately?

The message is immutable.

Basically my code is:

```
class NonActor {
    ....

    public void tellTest() {

         actorRef.tell("MSG", null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically `actorRef.tell("MSG", null);` creates a record like

```
(actorRef, Envelope(msg, sender))
```

and put it into `ActorSystem`'s message queue. Thus `tell` is not linked to the actor in any way. The `tell` method itself is undoubtedly thread-safe.

Comment: Those were my thoughts on its working as well, and indeed is.  Found in the docs and confirmed a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's thread-safe depends on the rest of your app.  Actors aren't inherently thread-safe; you can share mutable state just as you could with any application entity.  But the `tell` call will return immediately because it's asynchronous.

Comment: Do you mean depends on the msg itself?  As long as its immutable?

Comment: As long as the msg is immutable and the actor doesn't make use of any shared mutable state.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `!` operator.

It is defined like this in Akka classic 2.6 :

```
trait ScalaActorRef { ref: ActorRef =>

  /**
   * Sends a one-way asynchronous message. E.g. fire-and-forget semantics.
   * <p/>
   *
   * If invoked from within an actor then the actor reference is implicitly passed on as the implicit 'sender' argument.
   * <p/>
   *
   * This actor 'sender' reference is then available in the receiving actor in the 'sender()' member variable,
   * if invoked from within an Actor. If not then no sender is available.
   * <pre>
   *   actor ! message
   * </pre>
   * <p/>
   */
  def !(message: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit

}
```

`actorRef.tell("MSG", null)` is like `actorRef.!("MSG")(null)`, that forces the sender to be `null`.

If you use `!` outside an Actor, the implicit sender won't be found thus the default value `Actor.noSender` will be put by the compiler.

As long as the absence of sender is supposed to be automatically resolved at compile time, explicitly telling Akka it is `null`could be bug prone.

Never use `null` is Scala !

Answer (score 0):

The null as sender means that the receiving actor cannot execute sender().tell() to answer your message.